# add a column which represents difference with lag

Tags: r, excel

dataset is like

```
group  week  sum    

cat     1     10
cat     2      15
cat     3      20
cat     4      30
cat     5      35
dog     1      5
dog     2      10
monkey  1      6
monkey  2      14
```

requirement is like add a new column sum2 which is like

sum2 is sum(groupwise) -value(n-2),n=week
for example: for cat:sum=10+15+20+30=75
so sum2 values:

```
group  week   sum   sum2
cat     1     10    
cat     2      15
cat     3      20   75-week1value=75-10=65
cat     4      30   75-week1 value-week2 value=75-10-15=50
cat      5     35    75-10-15-20=30
```

Comment: why you didn't include `35`?  Do you need `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(sum2 = sum(lag(sum), na.rm = TRUE) - cumsum(lag(sum, n = 2, default = 0)) )`

Answer (score 0):

The condition is not very clear.  Looks like after grouping by 'group', get the `sum` of the `lag` of the 'sum' column and subtract from the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) of the `lag` of 'sum' where `n` is 2

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(sum2 = sum(lag(sum), na.rm = TRUE) - cumsum(lag(sum, n = 2, default = 0)))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups: group [3]
#  group   week   sum  sum2
#  <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
#1 cat        1    10    75
#2 cat        2    15    75
#3 cat        3    20    65
#4 cat        4    30    50
#5 cat        5    35    30
#6 dog        1     5     5
#7 dog        2    10     5
#8 monkey     1     6     6
#9 monkey     2    14     6
```

NOTE: If it is the group sum, then instead of `sum(lag(sum), na.rm = TRUE)`, it should be `sum(sum, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks for understanding...i got error like  Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Expecting a single string value: [type=double; extent=1]. Do you have any idea

Comment: Ignore the last comment..Great..It worked...solution did wonders.